# Debugging iPhone 3GS xcode 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode

I recently upgraded xcode to 4.2.1 (with macOS 10.7.3).

I have two iphone which one is 4GS and the other is 3GS. And when I upgraded both phone to iOS 5.1, 4GS works well but 3GS not works with following error message.

The version of iOS on “Test iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.

xcode says it support from iOS 5.0 (9A334).

And I want to know if this is from my mis-configuration of device or officially iPhone 3GS is not supported yet.

Is there anyone who suffers similar problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may want to go to xcode 4.3.1, which was released recently along with the 5.1 SDK.

After the installation you will have to re-install simulators for older iOS and debug support for older devices respectively even older iOS versions.

Out of the top of my head: In the top left corner of xcode in the drop down list where you select your build target and the targetting device/simulator there should be some menu item "install more simulators" or so. Click on that and follow the GUI. It is quite selfexplaining but the downloads may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

To develop in iOS 5.1 you have to upgrade sdk to latest one. I cant understand how you'r 4Gs worked fine